# Maintaining Approval status after restoring list items from recycle bin

Tags: powershell, restore, recycle-bin, status

I have recycled list items using powershell method `$deletedGuid = $item.recycle()`. After recycling, I have restored items from recycle bin again using poershell method `$site.RecycleBin.Restore($deletedGuid)` script. But after restoring, I see that all restored items have approval status as pending, why is that? Why the items did not maintained their approval status as before recycling?
I remember that some of the items have status as `Approved` and some have staus as `Draft` before recycling

Is there any possibility to maintain approval status of recycled items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there isn't as the `Restore()` function is almost equal to "Add new item". You could have a calculated hidden field which would store the Approval Status. During the restore you could check the value of that column and set Approval Status according to that.